# the error about async block outlive the current function

Tags: rust

in the case below，two closures，one is passed the compiler，the other is failed，why？

```
fn f() {
    let closure1 = |s: String| async {
        let s1 = s;
        println!("{s1}");
    };
    
    let closure2 = |s: String, b: bool| async {
        let s1 = s;
        let b1 = b;
        println!("{s1} {b1}");
    };
}
```

`closure1` is correct，but `closure2` is wrong, and the error is "async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `b`, which is owned by the current function
may outlive borrowed value `b`".

since both `closure1` and `closure2` use the outer `s`, why only `b` which `impl Copy trait`, cause error ?

normally after finish running `closure1`, `s` disappear, but the async block it returned does not even start to run, so when runs it, how to capture a non-exist `s` ?

does rust compiler has some special cases for this or maybe I missed some basic knowledge ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since both `closure1` and `closure2` borrow `s`

Ah but they don't: since `String` is not `Copy`, when you write:

```
let s1 = s;
```

this is necessarily a move, and thus requires that `s` be moved into the `async` block.

Meanwhile since `bool` is `Copy`

```
let b1 = b;
```

is a copy and thus only requires that `b` be captured by reference.

That is because `async` blocks are closer to closures than they are to "normal" blocks, and will similarly perform the "loosest" capture they need (they will capture by reference if all operations inside work on references). You can see this if you allow `s` to be captured by reference, by cloning it:

```rust
        let s1 = s.clone();
```

Now this won't compile anymore, for the same reason as `b`.

This is why `async move` blocks exist, with similar semantics to move closures: they capture everything by value, if you need any borrow it's up to you to set them up. If you convert your blocks to `async move`, the issue will be fixed because `b` will be moved (copied) into the async block first, then it will be copied again in `b1`. It also obviates the need for the locales, as `println!`'s ability to work off of references will be ignored:

```rust
fn f() {
    let closure1 = |s: String| async move {
        println!("{s}");
    };
    
    let closure2 = |s: String, b: bool| async move {
        println!("{s} {b}");
    };
}
```

compiles fine.

IME this is actually worse for `async` blocks than it is for closures as an async block "always escapes" its enclosing function while a closures routinely don't. Though the main issue is really that async closures are not stable yet, their stabilisation should make async blocks a lot less necessary, and thus mitigate their footguns.

I don't know if there are drawbacks to doing so, but I would suggest avoiding `async` blocks and always using `async move`, this makes the behaviour much more regular, and unlike closures it doesn't limit them, because borrowing async blocks rarely work.

Comment: so you mean `closure1` auto move `s` into closure, and the `async {...}` in fact change to `async move {}` during compiling ?

Comment: No, or I'd have written that. `s` is a parameter of the closure, there is no move into the closure. And `async` does not change to `async move`, `async` (and a regular closure) means that the compiler decides what to do for *each* variable being captured, depending how it's used. Since inside the block `s` gets moved (into `s1`), it necessarily has to be captured by value (moved into the block), otherwise it would not be moved into the local variable. `async move` is an instruction to the compiler not to do that, and to capture everything by value. It is *not* done implicitely by the compiler.

Comment: No matter how to capture `s`, the steps are

1. run `closure1` and pass `s` to it
`closure1("----".to_owned())`
the `s` ends its life after it finished
 
2. return the async block  
`let block = async { let s1 = s; println!("{s1}"); };`  
note that the async block in fact is sth like a closure, and it does not run. 

3. run the async block
`block.await`

now we start to execute the `let s1 = s;` code, and where is `s` ? `s` already disappear in step No.1,
how to captured a non-exist variable?

Comment: As I already wrote twice, `s` is moved into the async block. That happens when the async block is created. Just as with a closure captured values are moved in the closure when the closure is created not when it's executed.

Comment: When a closure captures a variable by value the variable is moved into the state of the closure, so it continues to exist for as long as the closure does. Similar logic applies to async blocks, so `s` is moved into the return value of `closure1`.

Comment: so the main difference between `async move {}` and `async {}` is just about whether move captured value into closure, (also the same theory on regular closure),  
`async move {}` will always force move every captured value in,  but `async {}` may move, may not, depend on compiler analyzing. for this question, the `impl Copy` captured value (`b: bool`) stop it consider moving ?

Comment: Pretty much yes.

Comment: thanks for your patient answering. I have another question, I repeat reading your answer,   "`let b1 = b;` is a copy and thus only requires that b be captured by reference.",   why compiler consider it (a `impl Copy` value) to capture by reference ? maybe it can use the same logic as `s` (move both `s` and `b` in),  and `closure2` can also work

Comment: A copy is *trivial*, and can be performed equality from a value or a reference, thus there is no cause to capture by value, as far as the compiler is concerned there is no cost advantage (or disadvantage).

Comment: I think this conditional move in `non-move` closure could make people confusing, cannot make sure whether variable is inside or outside, maybe it should be designed using the rule that `move` closure always move into,  `non-move` closure always stop moving (always captured by reference), it may be much clear

Comment: if so, `closure1` and `closure2` both report error, and I dont need to care what the arguments type is, since most time we dont write type explicitly